# JMeter - Function Helper's parameters panel hides parameters on more than 2 parameters

Tags: java, swing, jmeter, gui-design

When using Function Helper with function with more than 2 parameters, as __timeShift, it's hard to view and the parameters, because panel shows only 2 parameters in screen.

Can I enlarge parameters panel in UI to see all parameters?

If not can this be considered as a bug?

[FunctionHelper.java](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/e604181337062d537cd8609d55292ad1ecd49571/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/functions/gui/FunctionHelper.java#L204)

[image: 1]

Comment: under what os, os version, java version, screen résolution does it happen ?

Comment: and which version of JMeter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is scrollbar on the right no ?

[image: Function Helper Dialog with scrollbar]

You created a minor bug issue to make the table expand based on number of parameters:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64738

Comment: Yes this is the scroll bar, JMeter 5.3 on Windows

Comment: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64738

Answer (score 1):

Also you could enlarge the function helper dialog vertically. You will be able to see all the parameters in one view.

[image]

Comment: You are right, but it's still hard to see there are more parameters